# Migrate UrlHelper from ASP MVC 4 to ASP MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-devops

I have the solution structure

- MyProject.BusinessLayer
- MyProject.Web

The `MyProject.BusinessLayer` has a reference to `System.Web.Http.Routing.UrlHelper` which comes from (ASP MVC 4):

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Http.dll

I want to remove that dependency and use from existing MVC 5 version.

I have some questions?

- The UrlHelper in MVC 5 exist in System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper. Are they same?
- Is it correct to add `System.Web.Mvc` reference to `MyProject.BusinessLayer` ? *(I don't want to do this)*
- Is there a nuget from microsoft that contains that UrlHelper ?

Locally I have installed ASP MVC 4, but in Azure DevOps the build process fails:

> The type or namespace name 'UrlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: This has nothing to do with DevOps, you need to go back to the app and change things, then push and DevOps will build

Comment: Yeah I need to install nuget from `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core`  https://forums.asp.net/t/2096814.aspx?Where+do+I+find+system+web+Http
But now I wonder what are the differences between 4.0.0.0 and `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installing Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 2.3.3 fixed the problem